# Pinter a book of set theory exercise 5.2.3

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I cannot prove following problem so need help, Please give me some hint to prove this.

Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an indexed family of classes, where I is a set. Prove that there exists $J \subseteq I$  such that 
(i) $\{A_i|i\in I\}=\{A_j|j\in J\}$ and

(ii) in $\{A_j\}_{j\in J}$, each $A_j$ is indexed only once.
i.e., $A_i=A_j(i,j\in J)$ imply $i=j$.

using following theorem and axiom

Theorem:
If $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an indexed family of sets and $I$ is a set, then
(i)$\{A_i|i\in I\}$ is a set, and (ii)$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ is a set.

Axiom:Every set has a choice function $\gamma$

defintion of choice function: Let A be a set and write $\mathcal{P'}(A)=\mathcal{P}(A)\backslash \{\emptyset\}$

choice function is $\gamma:\mathcal{P'}(A)\rightarrow A$ such that $\forall B\in\mathcal{P'}(A)$, $\gamma(B)\in B$

Answer (score 1):

Define the following equivalence relation on $I$, $i\sim j\iff A_i=A_j$. Now define $X_i=\{j\in I\mid i\sim j\}$, then $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of sets. Use the theorem and axiom to deduce that there is a choice function from this family, say $f$. Finally, define $J=\{f(i)\mid i\in I\}$ and show that it satisfies the properties you want.